# how to increase height of the gridline in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, gridview, highcharts, height, gridlines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyy1a.jpg)

I want to change the distance between the lines of grid.while resizing it will be working fine, otherwise grid lines are overlapping.need to chart within the height of the widget.anyone please help with this..

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] with a [mcve]. An image is fine as to provide more context on a specific code — which is missing in this case. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the plot area depends on the height of the chart and other elements such as the legend or axis labels. If one of these elements, such as the legend, takes up more height, the height of the plot area is reduced.

So in your case, setting chart.height larger than the default should solve the problem.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 700,
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/von5ywjg/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height